# Can one use the word 'majority' for the leading alternative (in a three way split) even if the proportion in favor is less than 50%?

Tags: vocabulary

If there is a political proposition with three alternatives and the leading alternative, that is to say that which command the most support, does not have 50% or more support can that alternative be described as commanding a majority?

Or is a majority strictly defined as having 50% or more support?

Comment: Voted to close for lack of research because the answer provided clearly shows that the Q. could be answered by consulting a standard dictionary.

Comment: Americans in particular use the term [***plurality***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plurality) to mean *the part of a group of people voting that is the largest part, but not larger than the total number of other people voting.* They didn't actually get the "majority" of the votes (which ***always*** means more than 50%), but they were still the winners.

Comment: @TrevorD: can you then suggest what word is appropriate for a three way split?  Most dictionary definitions seem to imply a two way split.  So actually this question is more nuanced than your vote to close supposes.

Comment: What's wrong with the word used in your title: the **leading** group (or whatever)?  Some would argue that "alternative" is also wrong because it implies a choice between only **two** groups.

Comment: @TrevorD: accepting answer below as poster has found the term 'relative majority'.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after writing my comment!  But my comment about "alternative" still stands!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/majority) :

***MAJORITY***

a number or percentage equaling
 *more than half of a total*

// a majority of voters

// a two-thirds majority

Though in the special political context there are two terms:
relative majority and absolute majority.

According to  [Collin's Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english) :

***Relative majority***

the excess of votes or seats won by the winner of an election over the runner-up when no candidate or party has more than 50 per cent.

***Absolute  majority***

a number of votes totalling over 50 per cent, such as the total number of votes or seats obtained by a party that beats the  combined  opposition.

Comment: Relative majority, superb work!   https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/relative-majority

Comment: Worth noting Relative Majority is British English.

Comment: Just a clarification: does relative majority refer to the winning alternative party, or to the excess of votes that enabled them to win?

Comment: The relative majority party usually wins.

Answer (score 4):

The word 
[**plurality**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plurality) means, in the context of voting,

> 3c a number of votes cast for a candidate in a contest of more than two candidates that is greater than the number cast for any other candidate but not more than half the total votes cast

This answers your question directly - 'plurality' is used purposefully in distinction to 'majority' which is a half or more. So, no, you cannot use majority for any amount less than a half.

This seems not to be used in the UK, but is exactly what is used in the US. I have no idea on other anglophone communities (AusE, NZE, SAE, etc.)

Comment: I'm British, and I have never heard of this. I am very happy with accepted answer instead.  Do you think you might edit your answer to say this is the American English perspective?

Comment: @SMeaden Oh sure. But likewise for 'relative majority', that's just not a meaningful term in the US.

Comment: The first instances of _plurality_ in the sense of "largest minority" that I encountered were in U.S. Supreme Court opinions in which no opinion drew the support of at least five justices (judges) but in which at least five justices concurred in the result announced in the plurality opinion. In such cases it is actually possible for the plurality opinion not to be the largest minority opinion—if, say, three justices sign on to an opinion that reaches decision X for reason A, two justices sign on to one that reaches decision X for reason B, and four justices oppose decision X for reason C. ...

Comment: ... I wonder whether the U.S. sense of _plurality_ as "largest minority" evolved from the U.S. legal term _plurality_ meaning "most broadly supported of the opinions written in favor of a result favored by a majority of the court."

Comment: *Plurality* is definitely used in the UK; [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plurality) has a 'US' tag for the sense "number of votes gained when less than the total votes for the other candidates", but no such tag (and an example using the Conservatives) for "more support than the other candidate, party or idea", which is actually what OP asked about. The OED is (inevitably) less clear, having one sense *orig. Scottish* and OPs sense *orig.  and chiefly US*.

Comment: It is used in the UK, but perhaps only by people who care about such things (which is a minority of the population!)